# Dual Monitors with open source radeon driver - one stays black

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, display, radeon

Since I'm having a lot of problems with fglrx I wanted to use the open source Radeon driver on Ubuntu 15.04. As soon as I plug in the additional Monitor, the laptop screen turns off even though I can still move windows there.

The display settings utility detects both monitors, the external with a resolution of 1920x1080 and the Laptop screen with 1366x768.

`lshw -C video`'s output is:

```
sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: Trinity [Radeon HD 7520G]
       Hersteller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       Physische ID: 1
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:01.0
       Version: 00
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       Konfiguration: driver=radeon latency=0
       Ressourcen: irq:33 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:2000(Größe=256) memory:f0300000-f033ffff
```

`xrandr`'s output:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS connected 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I figured the `/etc/x11/xorg.conf` file might be useful, but turns out I don't have one.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Unity right?  This sort of thing works flawlessly on Xubuntu.  I think it's a thing with how they're working on convergence, and if you plug a phone in to a TV, you would only want the TV to show the screen...  so, it might be a bug by design.

Comment: Nope, I use Gnome. Although I remember having the same problem with Unity before, so I guess the problem goes deeper. It used to work without problems with fglrx, but after having problems with fglrx I switched to the open source driver.

Comment: I've had some problems recently involving even an Intel 5000 onboard.  So, it might be a deeper problem, not just fglrx.  Like making HDMI external primary even though internal is primary.  On a reboot, if external is not connected, you have no "Start Menu".  So, might not just be the driver.